# query using function “SUBSTR” of Firebird

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nhibernate, firebird

I need to write a NHibernate query using the firebird `SUBSTR` function with [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate), [queryover](/questions/tagged/queryover) or [nhibernate-criteria](/questions/tagged/nhibernate-criteria). I may do it with [hql](/questions/tagged/hql) or `SQL`, but these would be my last options.

Does anyone have any ideas? The following example query would be the SQL resulting from my NHibernate query:

```
SELECT *
FROM LANCAMENTO
WHERE SUBSTR(LAN_CD_CONTA, 1, 13) = :paramCd_Conta
```

Comment: Well, this question was not unclear from a NHibernate proficient user point of view as maybe me. Strangely enough, it does look that none of the closer voters has a single point in [tag:NHibernate]. (But maybe I have check their profile a bit too fast.)

Comment: Anyway Marcos, if you wish this to stay and not get deleted, you should edit your question maybe for rendering it more explicit even for non-NH users. I am going to edit at least the syntax, but as a "foreign" editor, I have to avoid going too "far", we must preserve original OP (you) intent.

Comment: A bit late, but I wonder, calling `.SubString()` directly in a Linq lambda may result in a call to the `substr` Firebird function. [tag:linq-to-nhibernate] does support `.SubString()` on strings. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, but I think it (.substring) does after you run the query and not when you send the query to the database.

Comment: No, if called on an entity property, it can only be run db side since the queryable will not know the property value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Linq, declare a SubStr extension method:

```
using NHibernate.Linq;

...

public static class CustomLinqExtensions
{
    [LinqExtensionMethod("SUBSTR")]
    public static string SubStr(this string dummy, int start, int length)
    {
        // No need to implement it in .Net, unless you wish to call it
        // outside IQueryable context too.
        throw new NotImplementedException("This call should be translated " +
            "to SQL and run db side, but it has been run with .Net runtime");
    }
}
```

Then use it on your entities:

```
session.Query<Lancamento>()
    .Where(l => l.CdConta.SubStr(1, 13) == cdConta)
    .ToList();
```

Beware, trying to use it without referencing an entity in its usage will cause it to get evaluated with .Net runtime instead of getting it translated to SQL.

Comment: I did with SAME sql pure, thanks for the help.